# Tables Needing To Same Width As The Rest of The Form

Tags: html, forms, textarea

In this page here https://dit.msr.mybluehost.me/forms/Zipline_Liability_Quote_Form.htm I have a form in which part of it is wider than the rest of it (specifically the SUPPLEMENTAL INFORMATION part down). I'd like the rest of that bottom half to line up with the top half in terms of width. I've tried going through the code and using max.width and or cols but I can't seem to get it to work. I've attached a screenshot of what the code for the SUPPLEMENTAL INFORMATION area looks like if this helps. [image]

Any and all help on this is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

First of all, erase all the `width="1000"` properties and instead give them a `width="100%"` and then wrap them all in a flex container and the flex container should have these styles:

```css
display: flex;
justify-content: center;
```

That's all.
As you can see [here](https://output.jsbin.com/pudowoy/), I removed some parts so that the length would be ok for sharing.

Comment: @jgar17 The HTML file is too large, which I cannot upload here as a code.